# OrientDB is slow when number of requests increases

Tags: orientdb

OrientDB is slow when the number of HTTP (REST) requests is high. (300 requests simultaneously)
I tried to set -Dnetwork.maxConcurrentSessions=15000 and MAXHEAP=-Xmx8512m, but nothing works. With 200 requests per second, the response time is good, but with 300 requests per second, the response time is horrible. (three or four times slower compared with 200 requests per second)
The CPU, memory, network and disk usage are ok.
Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have some script to reproduce the load?

Comment: No, because it is an application. Is there a configuration to increase the number of threads to respond?

Comment: Which version of Orient?

Comment: OrientDB Version 2.1.5

Comment: Which is the language of your application?

Comment: It is Java, but the access is HTTP REST only.

Answer (score 0):

Could you profile where most of the time is spent with a Java Profiler (like YourKit demo)? Or do you have a script I can run locally to simulate your workload?